# Hola gente, llevo estancado dias con un problema básico al enviar datos de formulario por medio de AJAX a PHP

Tags: php, ajax, formularios

espero se encuentren bien. Tengo un id en una URL, y en la misma pagina del URL tengo un formulario, el cual estoy enviando los datos por medio de AJAX. Pasa que deseo también enviar el ID que se encuentra en el URL, pero no encuentro la forma de enviarlo. Si deseas una mayor explicación, puedes ingresar al video donde explico lo que me pasa.
https://youtu.be/5AbUbDl19Ew
Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

////// FORMULARIO /////

```
<form class="formulario-pago" action='datos_compra.php' id="formulario-pago" method="POST">
        
        <div class="formulario">
            <h2>Datos personales</h2>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre completo" id="nombre_completo" name="nombre_completo"></input>
            <label>Fecha de nacimiento</label>
            <input type="date" id="fecha_nacimiento"  name="fecha_nacimiento">
            <input type="button" id="enviar-pago" class="boton btn-continuar" value="Continuar">
        </div>
    </form>
```

//// CÓDIGO JAVASCRIPT ////

```
$('#enviar-pago').on({
```

click:function(){

```
var formulario = new FormData($('#formulario-pago')[0]);

var nombre_completo = $('#nombre_completo').val(),
    fecha_nacimiento = $('#fecha_nacimiento').val(),
    correo_electronico = $('#correo_electronico').val(),
    ciudad = $('#ciudad-pago').val(),
    departamento = $('#departamento-pago').val(),
    opcionID = $('#opcion-identificacion').val(),
    identificacion = $('#identificacion-pago').val(),
    direccion = $('#direccion-pago').val(),
    detalles = $('#detalles-extra').val();
    
if(nombre_completo==='' || fecha_nacimiento==='' || correo_electronico==='' || ciudad==='' || departamento==='' || opcionID==='' || direccion==='' || detalles==='' || identificacion===''){
  
  Swal.fire({
    title: "Se te han olvidado campos por llenar",
    text: "",
    icon: "error",
    showConfirmButton: false,
    timer: 1000
  });
  
}else{
  formulario.append('nombre', nombre_completo);
  formulario.append('nacimiento', fecha_nacimiento);
  formulario.append('correo',correo_electronico);
  formulario.append('ciudad', ciudad),
  formulario.append('departamento', departamento);
  formulario.append('opcionID', opcionID);
  formulario.append('identificacion', identificacion);
  formulario.append('direccion',direccion);
  formulario.append('detalles', detalles);
  $.ajax({
    url: "../php's/datos_compra.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: formulario,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(){
      Swal.fire({
        title: "Compra satisfactoria",
        text: "",
        icon: "success",
        showConfirmButton: true
      });
    }
  })
}
```

}
})

Comment: Tienes un id que está en la url y quieres enviarlo por medio de ajax, eso???

Comment: si broooo eso mismo, lo dijiste bien facil xd

Comment: Antes que te agarren la pregunta a negativos, aquí tienes lecturas altamente recomendadas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 + https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour +https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Luego de leer y entender lo necesario para preguntar, edita la pregunta y agrega todos los elementos que sean mínimos y necesarios para reproducir tu escenario. Saludos.

Comment: El paso (1) para poder responderte es que mejores la pregunta: Explica en palabras lo que necesitas y añade el [MCVE], en tu caso el form y el js del ajax. El código debe ser mínimo, es decir no es necesario incluir más de un `input` en el form (porque es solo un ejemplo) ni cosas como `swal` que solo aportan ruido

Comment: Listo bro, perdona, tu respuesta me ayudó mucho mas a explicar qué es lo que quería. Ya hice los cambios solicitados, perdona si mi pregunta no fue clara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo 2 opciones:

##### 1) Agregar un input type=hidden al form

Y ahí guardar la ID. Es decir al PHP le llega la url `mipagina.com/pag.php?id=1`, tomas esa ID y la pones en el form

```
<form class="formulario-pago" action='datos_compra.php' id="formulario-pago" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>" />
```

Y luego la usas tal como los otros elementos del formulario

```
var nombre_completo = $('#nombre_completo').val(),
id = $('#id').val()
//etc

formulario.append('id', id);
```

##### 2) Obtener la id mediante javascript

La otra manera sería obtener directamente la variable desde la URL usando javascript. Con este método no necesitas PHP

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
formulario.append('id', urlParams.get('id'));
```

Comment: JSJAJSAJAJAJAJJ BROOOOOO MUCHAS GRACIAS, funcionó perfectamente. muchisimas gracias